# How to slow a thread down in JAVA

Tags: java, multithreading

I have this class in which I run a for loop 10 times. This class implements Runnable interface. Now in main() I create 2 threads. Now both will run loop till 10. But I want to check loop count for each thread. If t1 is past 7 then make it sleep 1 second so as to let t2 complete. But how to achieve this? Please see the code. I attempted but looks totally foolish. Just how to check the data of a thread ???

```
class SimpleJob implements Runnable {
    int i;
    public void run(){
        for(i=0; i<10; i++){
            System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName()+" Running ");
        }        
    }

    public int getCount(){
        return i;
    }
}
public class Threadings {
    public static void main(String [] args){
        SimpleJob sj = new SimpleJob();
        Thread t1 = new Thread(sj);
        Thread t2 = new Thread(sj);

        t1.setName("T1");
        t2.setName("T2");

        t1.start();
        try{
            if(sj.getCount() > 8){ // I know this looks totally ridiculous, but then how to check variable i being incremented by each thread??
                System.out.println("Here");
                Thread.sleep(2000);
            }            
        }catch(Exception e){
            System.out.println(e);
        }
        t2.start();
    }    
}
```

Please help

Comment: Isn't there a method to determine which thread is running code at a given moment?  If so, that could be used with an if statement to increment a per-thread value.

Comment: Sooo many questions. Why do you even want to execute the SAME job in multiple threads? And why would you want to "slow down" a computation. The problem you are trying to solve is unclear, and maybe if you explain what you want to achieve, you can get better answers.

Comment: @blackVegetable: sorry, I am total novice in java. I am afraid I couldn't understand what you said :(

Comment: @Jochen: take it easy. I am just experimenting. I just want to study threads. That's all. I am currently reading SCJP guide and trying out examples. I had some about sleep and join. Tried that, but wanted know how I can conditionally use these state altering methods

Comment: As a total novice, you should avoid threads that share data and read a primer on process synchronisation first. This is one of the domains where an intuitive solution to a problem is very likely to be subtly wrong.

Comment: If you already set the name, couldn't you check it against the Thread.currentThread().getName() you are already making use of?

Comment: You're 1) Modifying the same variable `i` from two different threads, and 2) Using an `if` where you likely want a `while` to busy wait, and 3) delaying the main thread instead of the target. Read more about threading, then try again, there's too many mistakes here.

Comment: @Erik damn....looks like it's GTFO time for me :(

Comment: I'm not very familiar with Java but one thing's for sure: if you consider slowing down a thread, it's the wrong approach. You should use proper thread synchronisation and try to make your threads run as fast as possible.

I have a hard time thinking of a situation when slowing a thread down would be the right thing to do.

Comment: @xxbbcc consider recent behaviour of youtube player. Notice when enough buffering has been achieved, then buffering simply halts. Pause a video it will load about 30-40% then no more loading. Only when you start playing it starts to load again. So it's somewhat a scenario where x amount of data was downloaded, so thread was either paused or sleep was performed

Comment: @Shades88 The idea is to have the threaded code *try* and run as fast as possible, and let the various synchronisation tools handle necessary pauses / slowdowns instead of micromanaging thread state yourself. One possible way to implement video buffering would be using a fixed-capacity buffer, such that attempts to add an element when the buffer is full make the thread *block*. The point is that it's the implementation of this buffer that would handle blocking and unblocking the threads accessing it, not code you write.

Comment: @Shades88 This also happens to be one of the "textbook" synchronisation scenarios ("producer-consumer"), and `java.util.concurrent` does have a class implementing a buffer with that behaviour, the [`BlockingQueue`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/BlockingQueue.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added a synchronized Block, which can be entered by one thread at a time. Both threads call and enter the method parallel. One thread will win the race and take the lock. After the first thread leaves the block it waits 2 seconds. In this time the second thread can iterate over the loop. I think this behaviour is wanted. If the second thread must not wait 2 seconds, too, you can set some boolean flag, that the first thread finished the block and use this flag in an if statement, which prevents the wait time of the second thread.

```
class SimpleJob implements Runnable {
int i;
public void run(){

    synchronized (this) {
        for(i=0; i<8; i++){
            System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName()+" Running ");
        } 
    } 

    try {
        System.out.println("Here");
        Thread.sleep(2000);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    for(i=0; i<2; i++){
        System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName()+" Running ");
    }
}

public int getCount(){
    return i;
}
}

public class Threadings {
public static void main(String [] args){
    SimpleJob sj = new SimpleJob();
    Thread t1 = new Thread(sj);
    Thread t2 = new Thread(sj);

    t1.setName("T1");
    t2.setName("T2");

    t1.start();
    t2.start();
}    
}
```

Comment: +1 for showing me the code..one question, where is the condition that if any of the thread say t1 exceeds 7 then it should join at the end?

Comment: The two threads do not join. The second thread has to wait until the first thread leaves the synchronized block. The synchronized block uses the object ("this") as a lock.

Comment: thanks, that was amazing. Now I can learn much more with this code. thanks again

Comment: You just reposted the code.  Care to say what you did and what the OP did wrong?  Otherwise this is a -1.

Comment: The two threads, for the first 8 loops, run in serial, not in parallel, since they share a lock.  While of some use for learning, this is not very useful code.

Comment: I misunderstood the question, I am sorry. Both should run total parallel and t1 should identify itself and sleep 1 secs.

Answer (score 7):

You should use some synchronization object, and not rely on slowing down of threads. I strongly suggest you take a look at one of the classes at java.util.concurrent package. You can use for this CountdownLatch - thread 1 will await on it, and thread 2 will perform the countdown and release the lock, and let thread 1 continue (the release should be done at the end of thread 2 code).

Answer (score 0):

If the goal is to run 2 Runnables in parallel (as Threads) and wait for them both to finish, you can, in increasing order of complexity/power:

1. Use Thread.join  (as suggested by @Suraj Chandran but his reply seems to have been deleted)
2. Use a CountDownLatch (as also suggested by @zaske)
3. Use ExecutorService.invokeAll()

EDIT ADDED

First, I don't understand what the magic "if you are at 7 then wait for the other" logic is all about.  But, to use Thread.join() from your main code, the code would look like

```
t1.start();  // Thread 1 starts running...
t2.start();  // Thread 2 starts running...

t1.join();   // wait for Thread 1 to finish
t2.join();   // wait for Thread 2 to finish

// from this point on Thread 1 and Thread 2 are completed...
```

Comment: ok, I can use join, but when? I want that when i is at 7 or greater for any of the thread it should join at the end. how can I achieve that